# Removendo uma classe de uma div ao clicar no option do select

Tags: javascript, html

Vamos lá, eu quero fazer o seguinte, quando eu seleciono uma opção do select ele carregue o texto do option selecionado e mostre em um textarea, até ai está ok, está funcionando, mas eu também queria que ao clicar em um option ele carregue uma div de acordo com o option selecionado. por exemplo eu clico no primeiro option ele carrega a div.one, quando clicar no option dois ele carregue a div-two e esconda a div.one e assim sucessivamente. Sendo que todas as divs devem começar escondidas por isso está com a classe hide. Obs: Quero fazer em javasript puro sem jquery.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>teste</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option  onclick="eventoClickNull()" value="">Selecione</option>
                        <option  onclick="eventoClick()" value="1">item1</option>
                        <option  onclick="eventoClick()" value="2">item2</option>
                        <option  onclick="eventoClick()" value="3">item3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <div divs class="one hide">
                      <p><b>DIV 1</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam maximus non magna id lacinia. Fusce blandit laoreet mi ut accumsan. Nullam at erat eget lectus condimentum iaculis eu vitae sem. Nunc lobortis tincidunt lobortis. Morbi leo diam, facilisis et convallis nec, aliquet et neque. Vivamus venenatis tincidunt nunc sit amet feugiat. Aenean tristique odio vitae sem tristique, sit amet euismod orci vehicula. In varius blandit est. Nunc sed augue fringilla, finibus nisi a, suscipit quam. Nullam feugiat velit eget mi vestibulum, at varius massa tincidunt. Praesent auctor, est sit amet interdum finibus, magna risus fringilla lectus, eu tincidunt tortor ipsum nec augue. Cras ut lectus tempor, ultricies mi non, ultricies risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed ut mauris arcu. Aliquam a mi mauris.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div divs class="two hide">
                        <p><b>DIV 2</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam maximus non magna id lacinia. Fusce blandit laoreet mi ut accumsan. Nullam at erat eget lectus condimentum iaculis eu vitae sem. Nunc lobortis tincidunt lobortis. Morbi leo diam, facilisis et convallis nec, aliquet et neque. Vivamus venenatis tincidunt nunc sit amet feugiat. Aenean tristique odio vitae sem tristique, sit amet euismod orci vehicula. In varius blandit est. Nunc sed augue fringilla, finibus nisi a, suscipit quam. Nullam feugiat velit eget mi vestibulum, at varius massa tincidunt. Praesent auctor, est sit amet interdum finibus, magna risus fringilla lectus, eu tincidunt tortor ipsum nec augue. Cras ut lectus tempor, ultricies mi non, ultricies risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed ut mauris arcu. Aliquam a mi mauris.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div divs class="three hide">
                        <p><b>DIV 3</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam maximus non magna id lacinia. Fusce blandit laoreet mi ut accumsan. Nullam at erat eget lectus condimentum iaculis eu vitae sem. Nunc lobortis tincidunt lobortis. Morbi leo diam, facilisis et convallis nec, aliquet et neque. Vivamus venenatis tincidunt nunc sit amet feugiat. Aenean tristique odio vitae sem tristique, sit amet euismod orci vehicula. In varius blandit est. Nunc sed augue fringilla, finibus nisi a, suscipit quam. Nullam feugiat velit eget mi vestibulum, at varius massa tincidunt. Praesent auctor, est sit amet interdum finibus, magna risus fringilla lectus, eu tincidunt tortor ipsum nec augue. Cras ut lectus tempor, ultricies mi non, ultricies risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed ut mauris arcu. Aliquam a mi mauris.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS

```
function eventoClick(){
    let e = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlSelect1");
    let itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    let textArea = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1");
    textArea.innerHTML = itemSelecionado

    let divs = document.querySelector('[divs]')    
    divs.classList.remove("hide")
}

function eventoClickNull(){
    let e = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlSelect1");
    let itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex = "0"].text;
    let textArea = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1");
    textArea.innerHTML = " "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Algumas coisas erradas:

- `let divs = document.querySelector('[divs]')` retorna o primeiro elemento, deves usar `querySelectorAll` e iterar com um forEach
- O `onclick` no elemento `option` não faz o que procuras, deves usar o `onchange` no `select`
- `e.selectedIndex = "0"` é uma atribuição, não uma comparação como pretendes...

A minha sugestão:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('exampleFormControlSelect1');
const textarea = document.getElementById('exampleFormControlTextarea1');
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('[divs]');


function eventoClick() {
  const selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex - 1;
  divs.forEach((el, i) => el.classList.toggle("hide", i !== selectedIndex));
  textarea.innerHTML = getSelectText(select);
}

function getSelectText(selectElement) {
  // a ideia de usar -1 aqui é só para o caso de ser `0`o código não ir buscar o texto do 
  // option e considerar como "não selecionável". Uma alternativa seria mascá-lo como "disabled"
  const selectedIndex = selectElement.selectedIndex || -1;
  const selectedOption = selectElement.options[selectedIndex];
  return selectedOption ? selectedOption.text : '';
}
```

```css
[divs].hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onchange="eventoClick()">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
        <option value="1">item1</option>
        <option value="2">item2</option>
        <option value="3">item3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div divs class="one hide">
        <p><b>DIV 1</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam maximus non magna id lacinia. Fusce blandit laoreet mi ut accumsan. Nullam at erat eget lectus condimentum iaculis eu vitae sem. Nunc lobortis tincidunt lobortis. Morbi
          leo diam, facilisis et convallis nec, aliquet et neque. Vivamus venenatis tincidunt nunc sit amet feugiat. Aenean tristique odio vitae sem tristique, sit amet euismod orci vehicula. In varius blandit est. Nunc sed augue fringilla, finibus nisi
          a, suscipit quam. Nullam feugiat velit eget mi vestibulum, at varius massa tincidunt. Praesent auctor, est sit amet interdum finibus, magna risus fringilla lectus, eu tincidunt tortor ipsum nec augue. Cras ut lectus tempor, ultricies mi non,
          ultricies risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed ut mauris arcu. Aliquam a mi mauris.</p>
      </div>
      <div divs class="two hide">
        <p><b>DIV 2</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam maximus non magna id lacinia. Fusce blandit laoreet mi ut accumsan. Nullam at erat eget lectus condimentum iaculis eu vitae sem. Nunc lobortis tincidunt lobortis. Morbi
          leo diam, facilisis et convallis nec, aliquet et neque. Vivamus venenatis tincidunt nunc sit amet feugiat. Aenean tristique odio vitae sem tristique, sit amet euismod orci vehicula. In varius blandit est. Nunc sed augue fringilla, finibus nisi
          a, suscipit quam. Nullam feugiat velit eget mi vestibulum, at varius massa tincidunt. Praesent auctor, est sit amet interdum finibus, magna risus fringilla lectus, eu tincidunt tortor ipsum nec augue. Cras ut lectus tempor, ultricies mi non,
          ultricies risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed ut mauris arcu. Aliquam a mi mauris.</p>
      </div>
      <div divs class="three hide">
        <p><b>DIV 3</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam maximus non magna id lacinia. Fusce blandit laoreet mi ut accumsan. Nullam at erat eget lectus condimentum iaculis eu vitae sem. Nunc lobortis tincidunt lobortis. Morbi
          leo diam, facilisis et convallis nec, aliquet et neque. Vivamus venenatis tincidunt nunc sit amet feugiat. Aenean tristique odio vitae sem tristique, sit amet euismod orci vehicula. In varius blandit est. Nunc sed augue fringilla, finibus nisi
          a, suscipit quam. Nullam feugiat velit eget mi vestibulum, at varius massa tincidunt. Praesent auctor, est sit amet interdum finibus, magna risus fringilla lectus, eu tincidunt tortor ipsum nec augue. Cras ut lectus tempor, ultricies mi non,
          ultricies risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed ut mauris arcu. Aliquam a mi mauris.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show de bola, obrigado pela explicação, mas ainda busco algo mais concreto, dessa forma usando toggle fica um pouco esquisito pois eu clico em um ai depois clico em outro o toggle se perde um pouco e as divs estão aparecendo juntas, no caso duas, queria algo usando this talvez, mesmo assim muito obrigado.

Comment: @FernandoPinhel tinha colocado `===` em vez de `!==`, ou seja a lógica estava inversa, escondia o selecionado e mostrava os outros. Corrigi.

Comment: Sim!! Beleza meu amigo, obrigado.